Does PHPunit reset local variables?
I have such as Testcase:
class GenerateTest extends AbstractTestCase
{
    private int $requestTime = 0;

    ...

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->requestTime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; // this is not null, verified by var_dump()
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] = $this->requestTime;
    }


I am getting the error
Cannot assign null to property GenerateTest::$requestTime of type int"

without a line number.
Even if I comment the lines in setup/teardown, I get the error. In the class are no further assignments to requestTime.
Where does this come from?
If i use ?int it works, but I want to understand the root cause.
Does PHPUnit "automagically" reset class variables?
EDIT:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class Test extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{

    private int $requestTime = 0;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->requestTime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; // this is not null, verified by var_dump()
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] = $this->requestTime;
    }

    public function testFoo()
    {
    }
}

is NOT an MRE - problem is not reproducible here. This is an integration test in Magento 2 context, have to dig futher.

"No" to the asked questions. Even if I comment the lines in setup/teardown, I get the error. Sounds like the error is coming from code that isn't in the question then :). I suggest assuming the error message does mean exactly what it says, and paring down the code until you find out how/why. Without an MRE it's not possible for folks to poke around, should they wish.

Note there are possibly-relevant configuration options with PHPUNIT

okay, can try to make a MRE, sorry
